# Slow Search since moving from 2003 Server to 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I moved a client from a old Windows 2003 server to a new fancy Windows 2008 R2 box.  I have been able to get everything to work properly except for the search function inside a program called Invoice 2 Go.  Invoice 2 Go searches small text files located on a file share.  On the 2003 server it is fast, but on the 2008 R2 box it takes minutes to complete

Comment: Did you enable indexing properly?

Comment: Have you confirmed the software has fully indexed the files? With Windows Search and large amounts of data/emails it can take hours or even days to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing was not enabled.  After enabling Windows Search and allowing the server to complete indexing this did not increase the speed of the search function.  I also tried enabling the old Windows 2003 Index service and setup a catalog for the folder but it did not help (and actually slowed down the entire server the next day).

Support from the developer is non existent.  Anyone have anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find out exactly what mechanisms 'Invoice 2 Go' uses, and then you can start optimising your new server for it. This might require clever use of something like wireshark.

Or figuring out where 2008 R2 treats the multiple opening of text files differently to 2003.

First thing I would try, is turning - or making an exception with - the antivirus on both client and server.